# Clipping where entire polygon is outside of bounds using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, clip

I'm trying to use QGIS atlas to generate a whole bunch of maps, based on a grid of polygons. What I planned to do was create a new grid square polygons within QGIS, clip the polygons that don't fall within the base layer, and then generate the atlas files from there.

However, when I try to Clip, where a polygon that I want to use as a reference for the atlas settings partially falls outside the base area, that polygon is clipped to the exact bounds of the base layer.

Is there a way that I can clip where any polygon that entirely or partially is covered by the base layer, the entire square polygon is retained, and only those that fall completely outside the base layer are clipped?

[image: Grid polygons with base layer for clipping]

Comment: 1. Select the grid polygons that intersect with your base layer and 2. than invert the selection and 3. delete them (In QGIS 3.2 Vector > Research tools > Select by location)

Comment: @Christophe I think you should write that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the grid polygons that intersect with your base layer and
2. than invert the selection and
3. delete them (In QGIS 3.2 Vector > Research tools > Select by location)